# Correctly testing an event handler in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a component with an anchor tag with an associated handler, onSelectLink().

```
<a
  :href="$t('footer.termsUrl')"
  target="_blank"
  name="termsAndConditions"
  @click="onSelectLink($event.target.name)">{{ $t('terms') }}</a>
```

The onSelectLink() function...

```
onSelectLink (buttonName) {
      buttonName === 'termsAndConditions'
        ? this.logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS)
        : this.logButtonClick(ANALYTICS.PRIVACY_POLICY)
    }
```

My unit test

```
describe('onSelectLink()', () => {
    it('[positive] should track analytics when user selects `Terms and Conditions` link', () => {
      const buttonName = 'termsAndConditions'
      jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'onSelectLink')

      wrapper.find('a').trigger('click')
      wrapper.vm.onSelectLink(buttonName)

      expect(wrapper.vm.logButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ANALYTICS.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS)
    })

    it('[positive] should track analytics when user selects `Privacy Policy` link', () => {
      const buttonName = 'privacyPolicy'
      jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'onSelectLink')

      wrapper.find('a').trigger('click')
      wrapper.vm.onSelectLink(buttonName)

      expect(wrapper.vm.logButtonClick).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ANALYTICS.PRIVACY_POLICY)
    })
```

My questions are:

1. Are these tests each invoking onSelectLink() twice?
2. Do I actually need to use "wrapper.find('a').trigger('click')"
3. Is this a good/robust test to make sure onSelectLink() is called with right argument?

When I comment out "wrapper.find('a').trigger('click')" the test still seem to pass. I thought I had to trigger the DOM event and then call the handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently triggering the `onSelectLink` twice in each test.

Once by

```
wrapper.find('a').trigger('click') // normal flow
```

and once by

```
wrapper.vm.onSelectLink(buttonName) // you run `onSelectionLink` directly on vm
```

The second one is wrong, in principle. You don't want to trigger the method by calling it directly on `vm`, because your users can't do that.
The only way they can do it is by clicking the link and that's what you should test.

```
const logger = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'logButtonClick')
expect(logger).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
wrapper.find('a[name="termsAndConditions"]').trigger('click')
expect(logger).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ANALYTICS.TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS);
```

Remember you can always use `console.log()` in your tests and you'll see the logged values in CLI and figure out what's going on.

Comment: One thing, in another component, I have a switch/case with 4 different cases. Each case is similar to 'termsAndConditions' and 'privacyPolicy',etc. The more accurate test you suggested works very well with the onSelect() function I have above. However, with the switch/case, the statement, `expect(logger).not.toHaveBeenCalled()`, fails the next test. For example, test one, 'termsAndConditions' passes, then the next, 'privacyPolicy' fails, and so forth. What can be done to clear the previous call. Also, does this happen because the test suite is reading off a stack of function calls?

Comment: I believe the caller results are actually an array, but for the case when it has only been called once `expect(caller)` automagically returns its only call (`[0]`) - because it's the most common case. I might be wrong and I have no means of testing now. But I do `expect(caller[0]).toEqual(yourFirstCall) && expect(caller[1]).toEqual(yourSecondCall)`.

Comment: @KevinT, However, you don't have to test them in the same test. You can test them in separate tests and they'd be good tests (as in, if there's any issue with one of them, that particular test will fail). But I get your desire to test them in the same test. It seems more elegant.

Comment: Yeah, I have one test suite and 4 'it' blocks. My code reviewers would complain about breaking them up!

Comment: By `test` I meant what you mean by `it` block. And, in fact, they're synonyms. `it(description, handler)` is an alias for `test(description, handler)`.